Identifying a movie about a man who can sense danger since he was a child
I can explain what I remember in blotches. My father was watching this movie on VHS when I was younger, I'd say about to 18-20 years ago (1996-1998) but not sure when the movie was made.
I roughly remember the first scenes when a father, mother, sister and the boy who were sleeping. The boy woke up and started to sense danger (I think his vision was starting to show colors, indicating danger), he decided to hide himself somewhere.  Soon later on, another scene was showing guards outside his house were killed, as if the danger is starting to happen.  Returning the scene back inside the house, the gunmen shot everyone in the house.
Another scene, the boy was training to fight, as he was learning the punches and air-kicks, the scene was showing him transitioning into a man (years going by)
Another thing I remember is the boy (now man) has joined the army. He was trying to run to safety, towards a helicopter with an injured solider on his side.  He started to get that danger-color-vision again, he stopped and managed to avoid a landmine.
That's all I really remember.  Would be awesome to know what movie this is.

Logan's War: Bound by honor seems quickly to fit your description. Else, this page can give you other example from that "power" used in SpiderMan and also other movies/tvshow, etc: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpiderSense

Wow! That's exactly what it is! Thank you so much!

@larme you should answer this with a synopsis or details that match.

You are looking for Logan's War: Bound by honor
From IMDB:

An Army Ranger infiltrates a mob family by posing as a hit man. In
  conjunction with his uncle, they are plotting revenge against the
  killers who murdered his entire family when he was young.

The Storyline in IMDB:

Logan Fallon was ten years old when his prosecutor father was marked
  for murder by a gangster he was prosecuting. Logan has this uncanny
  ability to sense danger before it happens, and he sensed the
  gangster's hitmen coming and survived their attack but the rest of his
  family was not so lucky. Logan chose not to tell the investigator who
  killed his family cause he wants to get them himself. He is taken in
  by his Uncle Jake who's an ex Army Ranger and a martial arts expert,
  he teaches Logan martial arts and gets him into the Rangers so that he
  could prepare himself to go after the people who killed his family.
  Written by 

Similarities from what you remember:
Sense of danger, family massacre, training.
